# Shaman.EPPlus + ASP.NET Core MVC - Part already exist exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, export-to-excel, epplus

I am using [Shaman.EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shaman.EPPlus/), a version of EPPlus that should be compatible with ASP.NET Core MVC.
I am trying to export a collection of object as xlxs file.
The code looks like this:

```
foreach(var client in clientsToExport)
{
    clientList.Add(new object[] { "FirstName", client.FirstName });
}

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();         
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Clients");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromArrays(clientList);
    pck.Save();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Clients.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
    Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

It seems that an exception containing the message "Par already exist" is thrown when GetAsByteArray method is called.

> at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage.CreatePart(Uri partUri, String contentType, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)
>   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save()
>   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray(Boolean save)

Do you know what could I check?

Comment: what did you return do you mind showing your whole example I am using .net core also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem are these line:

```
pck.Save();
....
var bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
```

Both calls will cause the package to be closed by Epplus.  You do not need the `.Save` call since that will automatically be called by `.GetAsByteArray` anyway so simply remove the first line.