# WebApi using EPPlus excel file download - error on open - unreadable content - repair

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, epplus

On my extjs webclient I hit a button and it downloads an excel template and populates data.  When I click on the CHROME popup to open excel file, it gives me the excel error message below.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?
The actual file looks fine to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my webapi code

```
        public HttpResponseMessage CreatePosSheet(string cName, string calcMethod, string username, int cid, HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        string templatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\tempLocation\");
        string templateFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplateFileName"];
        string templateName = string.Format("{0}{1}", templatePath, templateFileName);
        FileInfo xlTemplate = new FileInfo(templateName);

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        //MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ExcelSheet(xlTemplate, cName, calcMethod, username, cid));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Orders.xlsx";

        return response;
    }
```

here is the ExcelSheet code

```
        public byte[] ExcelSheet(FileInfo xlTemplate, string cName, string calcMethod, string username, int cid)
    {
        object[] tempObj = Orders(username, cid);
        List<TradeDetailDTO> tList = new List<TradeDetailDTO>();
        List<TempClass> acctList = new List<TempClass>();
        List<TempClass2> sectorList = new List<TempClass2>();
        tList = tempObj[0] as List<TradeDetailDTO>;
        acctList = tempObj[1] as List<TempClass>;
        sectorList = tempObj[2] as List<TempClass2>;

        #region set column variables

        int colAcctNum = 1;
        int colAcctDesc = 2;
        int colAcctTrdLvl = 5;


        int colCname = 6;
        int rowCname = 15;

        #endregion

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(xlTemplate))
        {

            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
            var wkshtFormula = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Formulas"];
            wkshtFormula.Cells[rowCname, colCname].Value = cName;

            package.Save();
            return package.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `ExcelSheet`?

Comment: Hi @Ernie I added the rest of the code above, do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the call to `.Save()`  since it will close the pck as a side effect.  See this for more info:

[Shaman.EPPlus + ASP.NET Core MVC - Part already exist exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064880/shaman-epplus-asp-net-core-mvc-part-already-exist-exception/40071302#40071302)