# trying to export to excel with epplus core and .net core

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application, epplus

I am trying to do an export to excel button when it gets hit I want to call this api and download an excel sheet.

my controller code looks like this and I am honestly stuck because I am unsure what I should be returning back. I am new to .net core api sorry

```
[Route("api/excel")]
public class ExportToExcel : Controller
{
    private readonly ScadaContext _context;

    public ExportToExcel(ScadaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetExcelMainView()
    {
        var query = _context.Main_View.Where(x => !x.MeterId.StartsWith("HOGC"));
        List<Object[]> MainViewList = new List<Object[]>();
        foreach(var p in query)
        {
            MainViewList.Add(new Object[] { "Battery Voltage", p.BatteryVoltage });
        }
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(stream)) 
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MainView");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromArrays(MainViewList);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Clients.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            var bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
            Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplest way to use one of the [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/micro) subclassess, 
such as [FileStreamResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult)

The controller method [File(stream,...,...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_) does it for you:

```
return File(stream, contentTypeString, willbeSavedWithThisFileName);
```

should just work. I'm not sure if you'll have to re-"wrap" your package in a memorystream again

```
var streamagain = new MemoryStream(package.GetAsByteArray());
```

(with the "handrolled" code you've already written, I'd try `return StatusCode(200)` as the way to get your Content back to the client).

Comment: I tried just adding return StatsusCode(200) it trys to download the excel sheet but it always says failed network error. I go to debug and I dont actually see the network path go to the sever and come back

Comment: Then forget that and go with `return File(stream,......)`? It is in any case less code. which is good.

Comment: so keep all of my code but do return File(stream, contentType what does this mean?

Comment: no replace the last four lines of your code (which edit the Response directly) with the one line, `return File(stream, contentTypeString, willbeSavedWithThisFileName);`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I am really not sure what to do this just keeps. it spins for about 20 min then sends back a 502 bad gateway. I am trying to debug it if I can make sense out of the debugger

Comment: a next debugging step may be to split your code into 2 steps. (1) save the excel package to a file on the server then (2) download the file. You can check whether your problem is step 1 or step 2.

Comment: idk why it isn't working I found this link and he is almost doing the same exact thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064880/shaman-epplus-asp-net-core-mvc-part-already-exist-exception/40071302#40071302